# C# WCF example in MSDN: where was CalculatorClient declared?

Tags: c#, wcf, msdn

Currently, I am studying WCF with C# and am currently on [part 6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730144(v=vs.110).aspx) (how to use a wcf client) of the tutorial/walkthrough.

I understand so far that to use the service, I have to add a service reference to the solution and I'm free to use the methods I've made in the service(specifically, in the service interface). As I study, I make it a point to trace where I declared objects (classes and methods) so I understand how it works.

I am confused though, in part 6 where was `CalculatorClient` declared?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using GettingStartedClient.ServiceReference1;

namespace GettingStartedClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Step 1: Create an instance of the WCF proxy.  
            CalculatorClient client = new CalculatorClient();
            //(what? i don't recall naming anything CalculatorClient!)

            // Step 2: Call the service operations.
            // Call the Add service operation.
            double value1 = 100.00D;
            double value2 = 15.99D;
            double result = client.Add(value1, value2);
            Console.WriteLine("Add({0},{1}) = {2}", value1, value2, result);
```

I tried looking back at  [part 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731835(v=vs.110).aspx), [part 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734686(v=vs.110).aspx), [part 3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730935(v=vs.110).aspx), [part 4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133(v=vs.110).aspx) and [part 5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734663(v=vs.110).aspx) but I never found the part where we declared this object. What I did to double check is to ctrl+f in all pages and look for traces off the word (CalculatorClient) but there isn't any. Even on part 6 there are only 3 traces of the word, never explaining where it came from!

At visual studio, intellisense says that Calculator client belongs to `(my solution).ServiceReference1`. But again, I don't recall naming anything that.

This bothers me since what if I am going to create my own wcf then? what will be the name of the client proxy then?

Answer (score 1):

Your link to [Part 4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133(v=vs.110).aspx) shows one of the ways to generate a client proxy using svcutil.exe utility. `CalculatorClient` in this case. Another automated way would be using Visual Studio "Add Service Reference..." command. Both way will generate a client class in a file named after it. The IDE way will put it into project. When you use svcUtil.exe you would need to add generated file to your project.

Comment: so, was CalculatorClient a default name given by svcutil?
There is no mention of the term CalculatorClient by the way. I tried doing part 4 again. Where was Calculator Client declared?

Comment: All names come from the wsdl file with service definition. This file is usually generated by WCF for you based on your service. The tutorial describes service creation and hosting. Based on what I see in part 2 the service was called CalculatorService so the default name for the client would be CalculatorServiceClient. Maybe they just shortened it in the tutorial. Sorry I did not follow it in details.

Comment: that's the thing, I dont recall ever typing a word named "Calculator" only. I do remember a "CalculatorService". So where exactly did "CalculatorClient" come from? This bothers me since what if I am going to create my own wcf then? what will be the name of the client proxy then?

Comment: You get to choose the name if you use IDE's "Add Service Reference..." I don't remember and don't see right now if/how can one specify it for svcutil.Sorry. Check svcutil's arguments. I do not see one specifically for the name but /out might be affecting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you view the Service Reference for the GettingStartedClient in the Object Browser, you can see the definition.